# __construct(): Argument #1 ($config) must be of type array, string given

Tags: php, laravel, api

I've created a Laravel project on Laravel 9.20.0 and I'm attempting to use an API wrapper for Linnworks I found on Github (https://github.com/booni3/linnworks-laravel) within my project. I'm okay with raw PHP but admittedly a complete beginner when it comes to Laravel and object oriented PHP.

In my /routes/web.php file I have:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\TestController;

Route::get('test', [TestController::class, 'test']);
```

In /app/Http/Controllers/TestController.php I have:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Services\OrderService;

class TestController extends Controller
{
    
    protected $orderService;

    /**
     * Instantiate a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(OrderService $orderService)
    {
        $this->orderService = $orderService;
    }
    
    
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function test()
    {
        $this->orderService->calculateProfit();
    }
}
```

In /app/Services/OrderService.php I have:

```
<?php

namespace App\Services;
use Linnworks;

class OrderService {

    public function __construct()
    {
        
    }

    public function calculateProfit()
    {
        $this->getOrder();
        return;
    }
    
    public function getOrder()
    {
        $order = Linnworks::Orders()->GetOrdersByNumOrderId(777678);
    
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($order);
        echo "</pre>";
        return;
    }

}
```

At this point, I'm just trying to figure out the correct way to use the Linnworks API Wrapper from GitHub within my service class and get it to return something from the Linnworks platform.

I have input the correct API details in the .env file but I'm clearly doing something wrong or missing something obvious (likely due to my lack of experience with object oriented PHP and Laravel) and I'm getting the following error when I load my url /test/:

`Booni3\Linnworks\Linnworks::__construct(): Argument #1 ($config) must be of type array, string given, called in /home/username/laravel-projects/project-name/vendor/booni3/linnworks-laravel/src/LinnworksServiceProvider.php on line 49`

According to the GitHub readme, usage is as simple as:

```
$orders = Linnworks::Orders()->getOpenOrders(
    25,
    1,
    null,
    null,
    'e41b4701-0885-430d-9623-d840d9d46dd6',
    null);
```

Any help or pointers in the right direction will be hugely appreciated as I've hit a bit of a wall.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Contact the dev, it's a miscode between this library and Booni3/Linnworks

Comment: Thanks for your reply - I've just removed Linnworks-Laravel via `composer remove booni3/linnworks-laravel` and added the base API layer via `composer require booni3/linnworks` and changed my code in OrderService.php to: `$linnworks = Linnworks::make($app_id, $app_secret, $token); $orders = $linnworks->Orders()->GetOrdersByNumOrderId(777678);` as per the booni3/linnworks readme

Comment: I'm getting a similar but different error: `Booni3\Linnworks\Linnworks::make(): Argument #1 ($config) must be of type array, string given, called in /home/username/laravel-projects/project-name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php on line 337` - I'm wondering if both are just not compatible with my version of Laravel

Comment: Their docs are incorrect. The definition is `public static function make(array $config, GuzzleClient $client = null): self`, so you need to pass in the full config as an array. See https://github.com/booni3/linnworks/blob/master/src/Linnworks.php

Comment: Excellent - thanks so much for pointing me in the right direction - the following works with the base API layer (Linnworks): ["applicationId" => $appID, "applicationSecret" => $appSecret,"token" => $token] - I'm guessing I'll just have to use Linnworks package instead of Linnworks/Laravel